# Accessing all vertices in a draw call from hlsl in SM4+

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

Say if i wanted to build matrices inside the gpu pipeline for vertex transforms, i realized that my current implementation is quite inefficient because it rebuilds the matrices from the source material for every single vertex (while it only needs to build it once per affected vertices really). Is there any way to modify the whole array of vertices that get drawn in a single draw call? Calculating the matrices and storing them in vram doesn't seem to be a very good option since multiple vertices will be getting processed at the same time and i dont think i can sync them efficiently. The only other option i can think of is compute shader, i havent looked into its uses yet but would it be possible to have it calculate the matrices and store them in the gpu so i can access them later on when drawing?

Comment: Just a small precision, what does SM4+ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any source code? I never calculate matrices in the shaders, normally do it on the CPU and pass them over in a constant buffer.

Comment: If you hardware instance, then you need to calculate world * VP on the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to precompute the matrix and send them to the shader as a uniform variable. For example, if your shaders only ever need to multiply the MVP matrix with the vertex positions, then you could pre-compute the MVP matrix outside the shader and send it as a float4x4 uniform to the shader, all the vertex shader does then is to multiply that single matrix with each vertex. It doesn't get much more optimal than that, since vertices are processed in parallel on the GPU and the GPU has instruction sets optimized for vector calculus.